# A script in Python stopped working after saving and turning VSC off

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I stumbled on this on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdlFhF6gjKo and decided to try to play with it a little. Of course I am a total newbie if it's about programming, Python and Visual Studio Code.

So I downloaded VSC, installed Python, pip installed python-binance, TA-lib, numpy and the websocket_client. I followed the video exactly up to about the half of it. My code was exactly the same and worked in exact manner. I run it multiple times, connecting with the websocket and getting streams of data which were showng in the terminal. The program would run until I manualy stopped it.

After getting to the half of it I decided to get some sleep because it was late. I run it for the last time, saved and shut down the computer. The next day when I got back to it, it was not working. It would run and stop after a second, not giving back any data, but no error as well. I checked the code a couple of times and it is identicall as the day before. Really frustrating...

So I thought I will try a different editor. I installed PyCharm. Pip installed the libraries and copied the code. After I run it in PyCharm I got "Process finished with exit code 0" and that it's. The program stopped. I can't establish any connection with the websocket, can't get any data from it, the code is unchanged, it was working fine, and without any logical reason, it is not working any more. This is so frustrating that I want to punch the monitor. Seriously I want to punch it. Even thou I know it's the cpu I rather should kick.

Help appreciated.

```
import websocket
import json
import pprint

SOCKET = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/adabusd@kline_1m/'

closes = []


def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')


def on_close(ws):
    print('close connection')


def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes

    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message['k']
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']

    if is_candle_closed:
        print('candle closed at {}'.format(close))
        closes.append(float(close))
        print('closes')
        print(closes)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with the version of the websocket library being different. WebSocketApp doesn't seem to be a function of the websocket library v.0.2.1.

Comment: https://websocketclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

Comment: The version installed is 1.2.1, WebSocketApp is a function they give as an example in their documentation.

Comment: That link 404s and pip is telling me there isn't a version 1.2.1 of the websocket library. What version of python are you using?

Comment: With your code, i can reproduce your question. after running it in terminal, no result but also no errors, just no reaction. Is there any possibility that the socket link is not effective? You may comment below the tutorial and ask the author.